# Order columns in R or Bigquery that are in date format mmm_yy i.e Oct_22, Nov_22, Dec_22 and so on while pivoting

Tags: r, sorting, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have the below unpivoted table.

| Metric | Month | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Customer_count | Oct_22 | 500 |
| Sum_of_Txn_Value | Oct_22 | 20000 |
| Customer_count | Nov_22 | 450 |
| Sum_of_Txn_Value | Nov_22 | 15000 |
| Customer_count | Dec_22 | 350 |
| Sum_of_Txn_Value | Dec_22 | 12000 |
| Customer_count | Jan_23 | 250 |
| Sum_of_Txn_Value | Jan_23 | 10000 |

**Desired output:** Pivoted dataframe with the sorted dates in the column 'Month' in the new columns using R or Bigquery.

| Metric | Oct_22 | Nov_22 | Dec_22 | Jan_23 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer_count | 500 | 450 | 350 | 250 |
| Sum_of_Txn_Value | 20000 | 15000 | 12000 | 10000 |

**What I'm getting:** Pivoted dataframe with the unsorted dates in the new columns

| Metric | Oct_22 | Jan_23 | Dec_22 | Nov_22 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer_count | 500 | 450 | 350 | 250 |
| Sum_of_Txn_Value | 20000 | 15000 | 12000 | 10000 |

Comment: `pivot_wider()` should order the columns by first appearance which should give the desired order already based on your table. Otherwise you should be able to specifiy order by using names_sort = TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

In R I would use a data table to sort columns

```
library("data.table")
df2 <- setorder(df,date)
df2
```